# How can I change the control group for my dummy variables in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am using R to run a linear regression. I have a group of 3 dummy variables that represent 4 plots of land (labeled as group 1, 2, 3, and 4). I would like to set Group 4 as the control group when I generate the dummy variables, but R sets group 1 as the control by default. I have tried changing the contrasts.arg, but that does not appear to work.

```
ferti.f = factor(ferti)
model.matrix(~ferti.f, contrasts.arg = c(1, 2, 3))
```

My output looks like the following:

```
   (Intercept) ferti.f2 ferti.f3 ferti.f4
1            1        0        0        0
2            1        1        0        0
3            1        0        1        0
3            1        0        0        1
```

Whereas I would like something like below using the same data:

```
   (Intercept) ferti.f2 ferti.f3 ferti.f4
1            1        1        0        0
2            1        0        1        0
3            1        0        0        1
3            1        0        0        0
```

I feel like I am doing the contrasts.arg incorrectly, but don't know how to correct it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you may be looking for the [relevel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872070/how-to-force-r-to-use-a-specified-factor-level-as-reference-in-a-regression) command

Comment: Try relevel() command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off of the comments above, the problem was solved like this:

```
ferti.f = factor(ferti)
ferti.f = relevel(ferti.f, ref = 4)
model.matrix(~ferti.f)
```